# Background package command \backgroundsetup not working in environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, backgrounds

I am currently designing an application template for myself and maybe some colleagues and I have a little trouble with \backgroundsetup.

The structure of the document I am aiming for shall look as follows

```
    \begin{document}

       \begin{coverletter}
          some text
       \end{coverletter}

       \begin{application}
          some text
       \end{application}

       and so on

    \end{document}
```

In each environment, I would like to set the background based on a pdf-file. However, \backgroundsetup does not work if I call it inside either \newenvironment or \NewEnviron.

Can anyone help me to fix that?

Here a minimum example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
    \backgroundsetup{
        scale=1,
        opacity=1,
        angle=0
    }

\newcommand*{\setbackground}[1]{\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[height=303mm, width=216mm]{#1}}}}

\NewEnviron{coverletter}{\setbackground{bg}\BODY}
%\setbackground{bg}

\begin{document}

   \begin{coverletter}          
      This is a test        
   \end{coverletter}

\end{document}
```

bg is the background image and should work with any DinA4 pdf document.

Thanks a lot advance!

Comment: Most likely the change from `\backgroundsetup` gets lost inside the group formed by the environment -- it is unknown then when the page is shipped out

Comment: Is `\NewEnviron{coverletter}{\setbackground{ente}\BODY}[\clearpage]` acceptable for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I finally ended up with the following code. Just in case someone wants to do something similar in the future.

```
\newcommand{\topbar}{\draw[fill=dark, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (216mm,-83mm);}
\newcommand{\narrowtopbar}{\draw[fill=dark, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (216mm,-23mm);}
\newcommand{\sidepanel}{\draw[fill=light, draw=none] (13mm,-23mm) rectangle (83mm,-280mm);}
\newcommand{\footer}{\draw[fill=light, draw=none] (0mm,-303mm) rectangle (216mm,-290mm);%
    \filldraw [fill=dark, draw=none] (184mm,-292.5mm)  coordinate (GeneralStart) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(+3.2,0) -- ++(0,-1.05) -- ++(-4.0,0) -- cycle;}

\newcommand{\setbg}[1]{%
    \AtBeginPage{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[xshift=-108mm, yshift=151.5mm] at (current page.center)
        {%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            #1
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
```

I can then call `\setbg{\topbar\sidepanel\footer}\clearpage` to set my page-background. Note, that the `\AtBeginPage`-command is provided by the  bophook-package.